# Installed Ubuntu 13.10 not Found after forced shutdown

Tags: boot, system-installation, mount

Couple of days ago, I installed Ubuntu 13.10 and I was enjoying it until I wanted to import files from my external hard drive that it suddenly froze for 20 min or so and I forced shutdown my laptop. Right after, when I hit the start, the nice statement

```
OS not Found
```

was in front of my eyes.

I tried booting it from usb and even wanted to reinstall it but it said I don't have enough space which I'm sure I have 290GB free!

1. How can I retrieve Ubuntu?
2. Is there any chance that my HDD is broke? (I changed the BIOS order to HDD, but nothing's happened.)

and

> when I boot from usb why I cannot access to my HDD? i.e. gparted only shows the usb and nothing else! (I even tried "*grub-install /dev/sda*" but then it says "*path /boot/grub" is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible.Aborting*."

I'd appreciate any suggestions or help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As guessed, my HDD was broke so I replaced it with the new one and back to enjoy Ubuntu 13.10 :)

Answer (score 0):

The force shutdown might have got your HDD corrupt. While re-installing Ubuntu, try to recover your files and then wipe your HDD. Merge all partitions and do a clean install on your Hard Drive. Good Luck!

Comment: Dear Aryan, Thanks for your comment. Yes, this is my initial guess, but the thing is I cannot re-install it as it says there is not enough space and only recognizes my usb or any other external hard drives.